# How to deal with mobile browsers eating key/mouse events

Tags: android, browser, dom-events

I've got some Javascript code that I have written which captures both keyboard and mouse events.  The idea is that whenever I tap on an element (a TD) on the page it gets selected (basically I just change the class so it is highlighted), and I can use the arrow keys to change which element is selected.

However, when I view this page on the stock android browser on my phone (running Gingerbread), the browser eats all the events and my page is non-functional.  Specifically, when I tap on an item on the page I see an orange colored rounded box surrounding the text, and my page does not get the event.  When I hit the up and down arrow key, the box moves, but my code is not doing this, it appears to be something the browser is doing.

I suspect that what is happening is that the browser is trying to be "helpful" somehow.  What I'm looking for is some way to give the browser a hint to not do this, or otherwise disable this behavior.

Update: Here is a more specific example of the problem I am seeing.  I set up the following simple listener just to see what key code correspond to various keys:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    alert(evt.which)
}
```

Now, if the cursor is in a TextField and I hit the enter key on my phone, the alert pops up and says "13".  BUT if I move focus away to another element (in this case a TD), when I hit enter, *NOTHING HAPPENS*.

Update: I have tried installing a half dozen different browsers.  They all seem to swallow up the arrow keys (this is a physical keyboard on the device) and use them to scroll the screen around or to highlight different elements on the page, instead of passing the event to my web app so it can actually use them to do what I want to do!  The only browser I have seen that does not do this is Firefox, which seems to just silently ignore them completely.

Comment: Have you tried the jqtouch library?

Comment: no. my current approach has been to simply define alphabetic characters to perform the same commands (resembling how vi works).  if jqtouch worked, i would need to try to reverse engineer the thing to figure out how it works.